# Please strip trailing whitespace from codeblocks

Tags: feature-request

I've just posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52709319/674039) with a code block copy-pasted from my tty ([zsh](https://ohmyz.sh)) and it turned out looking like this:

```
>>> haystack = "qabcdzzzefgyyyh"                                                                                                                                                                                                               
>>> needle = "acgh"                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
>>> it = iter(haystack)                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
>>> all(x in it for x in needle)                                                                                                                                                                                                               
True
```

Big horizontal scrollbar.  I had to manually edit it to look like this:

```
>>> haystack = "qabcdzzzefgyyyh"
>>> needle = "acgh"
>>> it = iter(haystack)
>>> all(x in it for x in needle)
True
```

Could we strip trailing whitespace off lines automatically, when submitting a post?

Comment: Then how would you ask questions about [Whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_%28programming_language%29) :)

Comment: What if the issue the person is having is related to the trailing white space or more accurately invisible characters in the trailing whitespace?

Comment: Just stripping [space](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm) (0x20) would be okay, no need to include other weird invisible characters.

Comment: I also think that the user should be responsible for formatting to a degree and not depend on the system to remove content like trailing spaces that they think should not be there.

Comment: Many text editors and IDEs provide this convenience, is there a reason why you think it would not also be a helpful feature for the text editor in the website's UI?

Comment: At a base level, I don't disagree with this request.  But to answer your posit, given that I am fully conscious that this is a website, I should not have any expectation whatsoever that the website will provide any extra clean-up of the content I post, including stripping whitespace.  I would fully expect that the whitespace in my post is preserved if one day I have a situation where some clever engineer decided to make all of their CSS class identifiers different kinds of whitespace.

Comment: In a text editor the user can chose to use or to not use the feature. What you are suggesting is removing the choice for the user. If you wanted to suggest a feature to add the ability to strip trailing whitespace when the user clicks a button that would be different then enabling it by default.

Comment: @Makoto please don't give them ideas:(

Comment: @MartinJames:  It's too late.  I thought I had the question favorited which did this, but I guess I didn't.

Comment: Well, right now it's causing problems for me. And these situations where it might be undesirable to strip trailing whitespace by default seem contrived, but perhaps it could be an opt-in feature to turn on in the user preferences in that case.

Comment: So to fix a simple problem that pasting into an editor that you can strip trailing whitespace with you want the stack exchange devs to code an entire new feature that people would have to opt-in to use?

Comment: No, I just post on meta to gauge if the idea is popular or not. Sheesh...

Comment: In Fortran fixed form source all lines (with default characters) are exactly 72 columns wide, having trailing spaces as necessary.

Comment: Interesting. Can you actually find a Fortran question which is doing that? I [searched](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fortran+%22fixed+form%22) and couldn't find a single one.. even the questions talking about fixed form are not using 72 cols in their code snippets.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218248/trailing-spaces-when-copying-from-console

Comment: To be fair, I'm not aware of a compiler doing anything other than padding short lines or not caring about short lines.  Any asker using punch cards has greater problems than how SO formats the code.

Comment: @wim to do that search, you have to visit SO offices and look through a warehouse full of Hollerith card packs.  There may be spiders..

Comment: @HansPassant  Thanks for the link. Was able to solve the issue at the source, after reading that post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Well, right now it's causing problems for me. And these situations where it might be undesirable to strip trailing whitespace by default seem contrived, but perhaps it could be an opt-in feature to turn on in the user preferences in that case.

There's a number of issues with this:

- User preferences aren't the most discoverable. Whether this preference is defaulted to on or off, unless it's thoroughly documented within the editor itself, users aren't going to realize there's a way to toggle it (and frankly most users aren't expecting this sort of feature to be in a post editor).
- You aren't going to know in advance when your next problem might turn out to be a problem with whitespace. If you turn or leave it on and it strips the problematic whitespace from your question, you'll find yourself in the situation Laurel describes, hunting around only to eventually find out that the editor was tampering with your MCVE (so it no longer meets the V criteria) — only, this time because you asked it to.

If this sort of feature *were* to be added to the editor, it should be a formatting tool you use on demand with arbitrary selections (including the entire post, if you so choose), not an automated filter. Some text editors and IDEs may offer this feature, though most I see only have the option of stripping trailing whitespace from the entire document. But even then I'd make sure my code actually still reproduces the problem as expected once the whitespace is stripped... and the better place for me to be doing that is within my IDE, not the Stack Overflow post editor, since that's where I'd be running my code.

Comment: Seeing same issue in questions occasionally:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/53162817/674039

Comment: @wim: Well, there's a reason I use the term "post" consistently in my answer... seeing as this is a terminal-specific quirk I don't see why it would be limited to answers.

Answer (score 17):

Wouldn't be a fan of this, personally. If you don't want the whitespace there, then just delete it - it's not that hard!

There's always going to be that weird esoteric question asked in the future that relies on said whitespace being there, and then we're just going to get a corresponding meta question entitled "Please *don't* strip trailing whitespace from code blocks."

Answer (score 11):

Removing the spaces will change the meaning of some code. In particular, it will affect:

- [Multiline strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(strings)#Multiline_string)
- Regexes which end in one or more spaces
- Languages that require fixed length lines of code, as  francescalus notes in the [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375100/please-strip-trailing-whitespace-from-codeblocks#comment636660_375100) is the case for FORTRAN.

What's worse is that this change is so subtle that it could take at least an hour for someone to figure out what went wrong with their code between the time when they wrote it and the time when someone comments that it doesn't work. It's not something that would be expected, so it's not something people would be looking out for. I've had this same sort of change (specifically `...` was changed to `…` automatically when pasting into an IDE that used a non-fixed-width font) and it took me about an hour to find out what happened.

Comment: Multiline strings *is* a good point.  But some IDE have this same situation and take care around it (for example, PyCharm will detect if within a multiline string and does not strip trailing whitespace in that case). For regex, I don't understand your point, it will still need the closing quote character.  And FORTRAN .. well, I assume those developers will have passed by the time this feature would get implemented.

Comment: @wim An IDE deals with a single known programming language. On Stack Overflow, you don't necessarily know what programming language is being used in a code block, or even if it's actually code and not English formatted as code.  My point is that there are many cases where removing whitespace would be bad. It's much too complex to account for everything and it would be simply easier to remove the whitespace by hand or ignore it when it's not needed.